# uid is not defined for type 'Object' in flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, firebase-realtime-database, userid

i am trying to check if a user id is the same as the current user's id by using data.uid but i keep getting this error:

> The getter 'uid' isn't defined for the type 'Object'.

this is the code

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return FutureBuilder(
        future: Future.value(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser),
        builder: (context, futureSnapshot){
          if(futureSnapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting){
            return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator(),);
      }
           return StreamBuilder <QuerySnapshot>(
      stream: firestore.collection('chats').orderBy('timeStamp', descending: true).snapshots(),
      builder:(ctx, chatSnapshot){
      if(chatSnapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting){
        return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator(),);
      }
      final chatdocs = chatSnapshot.data!.docs;
      
      return ListView.builder(
        reverse: true,
        itemCount: chatdocs.length ,
        itemBuilder: (ctx, index) => messageBubble(
          chatdocs[index]['text'],
          chatdocs[index]['userId'] == futureSnapshot.data!.uid, //this is the error
          )
        );
        }
        );
    } );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you don't declare the type of the `Future` in your `FutureBuilder`, it resolves to an `Object`. And an `Object` doesn't have a `uid` property, which is why you get the error.

To solve this declare the type of your `FutureBuilder`, which in your case would be:

```
return FutureBuilder<User>(
```

---

Note that I have no idea why you're using a `FutureBuilder` here to begin with. The `FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser` is a synchronous value, so you don't need a `FutureBuilder` to access it. Removing the `FutureBuilder` would lead to the exact same result.

If you're trying to make your code respond to auth state changes, like that it takes a moment for Firebase to restore the user's sign-in state when you start the app, you'll want to actually listen to `authStateChanges` with a `StreamBuilder` for that nowadays, as shown in the first code snippet in the documentation on [getting the current user](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/flutter/manage-users#get_a_users_profile). Here too, you'll want to declare your `StreamBuilder` with a `User` type, just like we did above for the `FutureBuilder`.

Comment: thank you for your help I'm actually new to flutter and i was following a code from youtube, so what you suggest is that I delete the `FutureBuilder` block and instead of  `StreamBuilder <QuerySnapshot>`  it becomes `StreamBuilder <User>`  and inside it i call `FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser` ?

Comment: Inside the `StreamBuilder` you can either use `FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser` is (simpler) the `user` that the stream gives you.

Answer (score 0):

You can try json decoding your variable into the object User you are looking for:
If the `futureSnapshot.data` is a user you'll be able to use the `uid` as a map key to check with `chatdocs[index]['userId']`

Like this:

```
import 'dart:convert';

final Map<String, dynamic> _valueMap = json.decode(futureSnapshot.data!);

chatdocs[index]['userId'] == _valueMap['uid'];
```

Comment: This is not really an answer. That variable Object has nothing to do with the Dart version. The most likely scenario is that "data" is either null or "uid" doesn't even exists inside "data". If you are going to ask, use the comment section of the question.

Comment: On the first read i thought it was a compiler problem related to firebase user as on the transition between dart sdk 2.17 and 2.18 they fixed the compiler not identifying the object as an user so we had to do things like: 

final User? user = snapshot.data as User?;

Reading again it seems like the user is a structure stored in the database

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code:

```dart
StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
  stream: firestore.collection('chats').orderBy('timeStamp', descending: true).snapshots(),
  builder: (ctx, chatSnapshot) {
    if (chatSnapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
      return const Center(
        child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
      );
    }

    final List<QueryDocumentSnapshot<Object?>> chatdocs = chatSnapshot.data!.docs;
    final String uid = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser?.uid ?? '';

    return ListView.builder(
      reverse: true,
      itemCount: chatdocs.length,
      itemBuilder: (ctx, index) {
        final Map<String, dynamic> chat = (chatdocs[index]).data() as Map<String, dynamic>;

        return messageBubble(
          chat['text'],
          chat['userId'] == uid,
        );
      },
    );
  },
),
```